# Python:Getting text from html using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, kaggle

I am trying to extract the ranking text number from this link [link example: kaggle user ranking no1](https://www.kaggle.com/titericz). More clear in an image:

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    sourceCode = requests.get(item_url)
    plainText = sourceCode.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText)
    for item_name in soup.findAll('h4',{'data-bind':"text: rankingText"}):
        print(item_name.string)

item_url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/titericz'   
get_single_item_data(item_url)
```

The result is `None`. The problem is that `soup.findAll('h4',{'data-bind':"text: rankingText"})` outputs:

`[<h4 data-bind="text: rankingText"></h4>]`

but in the html of the link when inspecting this is like:

`<h4 data-bind="text: rankingText">1st</h4>`. It can be seen in the image:

[image]

Its clear that the text is missing. How can I overpass that?

Edit:
Printing the `soup` variable in the terminal I can see that this value exists:
[image]

So there should be a way to access through `soup`.

Edit 2: I tried unsuccessfully to use the most voted answer from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118337/fetch-data-of-variables-inside-script-tag-in-python-or-content-added-from-js). Could be a solution around there.

Comment: When I inspect the source of that page it looks like `<h4 data-bind="text: rankingText"></h4>` ... so the result seems correct.

Comment: I have edited my question. You can see in the screenshot the value exists.

Comment: The url in your code is different from the one in your linked example; this was confusing. I would suggest changing the one in your code to match the example or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the observation.Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't going to try browser automation through `selenium` as @Ali suggested, you would have to *parse the javascript containing the desired information*. You can do this in different ways. Here is a working code that locates the `script` by a [regular expression pattern](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression), then extracts the `profile` object, loads it with [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) into a Python dictionary and prints out the desired ranking:

```
import re
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


response = requests.get("https://www.kaggle.com/titericz")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

pattern = re.compile(r"profile: ({.*}),", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

profile_text = pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
profile = json.loads(profile_text)

print profile["ranking"], profile["rankingText"]
```

Prints:

```
1 1st
```

Comment: Can I ask what is the purpose of `re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL` in the `re.compile` function?

Comment: @MpizosDimitris these are just regular expression flags - [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) enables the multi-line search, [`DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) allows `.` match a multi-line character also.

Answer (score 3):

The data is databound using javascript, as the "data-bind" attribute suggests.

However, if you download the page with e.g. `wget`, you'll see that the rankingText value is actually there inside this script element on initial load:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
profile: {
...
   "ranking": 96,
   "rankingText": "96th",
   "highestRanking": 3,
   "highestRankingText": "3rd",
...
```

So you could use that instead.

Comment: Isn't `highestRanking` different than `rankingText`?

Comment: Yes thanks, highestRanking is 1 while rankingText is "1st". Seems that it's actually "rankingText" he should be looking for. That's entirely based on a quick glance at the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your problem using regex on the plain text:

```
def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    sourceCode = requests.get(item_url)
    plainText = sourceCode.text
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")
    pattern = re.compile("ranking\": [0-9]+")
    name = pattern.search(plainText)
    ranking = name.group().split()[1]
    print(ranking)

item_url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/titericz'
get_single_item_data(item_url)
```

This return only the rank number, but I think it will help you, since from what I see the rankText just add 'st', 'th' and etc to the right of the number

Answer (score -1):

This could because of dynamic data filling.

Some javascript code, fill this tag after page loading. Thus if you fetch the html using requests it is not filled yet.

```
<h4 data-bind="text: rankingText"></h4>
```

Please take a look at [Selenium web driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). Using this driver you can fetch the complete page and running js as normal.