# How to get data from <script> with var using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, json, parsing, beautifulsoup

Using arsenic library to scrab webpage, and then beautifulsoup to parse page source. Soup contains a large html with lots of scripts. I need -9 from the end.

```
page_source = await session.get_page_source()
    soup = bs(page_source, 'html.parser')
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    script9 = scripts[-9].next
```

here is script9:

```
    sometext;
var thumbdata = {
  thumbs: [{avatar: "/i/nophoto.jpg", username: "IslandGirlSearching",la:"0 second ",chatid: "0",userid: "2088789", age:"21",city:"Cebu"},{avatar: "/p/2021-08/Cristina266/ava-1629535964.jpg", username: "Cristina266",la:"0 second ",chatid: "0",userid: "2095868", age:"26",city:"Pasig City"}  ] }; 
  var source = sometext;
```

then i follow example you shared:

```
    pattern = re.compile(r"var thumbdata = {\n"
                         r"(.*?);")

    m = pattern.match(script9.string)
    thumbs = json.loads(m.groups()[0])

    for thumb in thumbs:
        print(thumb)
```

Checked my regex, its correct. But when i do this code, i get attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch data of variables inside script tag in Python or Content added from js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118337/fetch-data-of-variables-inside-script-tag-in-python-or-content-added-from-js)

Comment: i guess it is, now i am trying  to get correct reg expression to match it. I will appreciate if you could help with this.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make your code conform to the [mre] guidelines and include some minified sample data for `page_source`, perchance?

Comment: edited my question, hope its better now

Comment: Can you add a bit of clarity on how you *know* that your RegExp pattern is "*correct*"?

Comment: i checked on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/W3hlfZ/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with your approach still:

1. To pass a string to `json.loads()`, it needs to be valid JSON; otherwise, you'll get exceptions. For what you're attempting to capture, you need to include the leading `{` token as part of your capture group. Consolidate your two separate patterns as such:

   ```
   var thumbdata = ({\n.*?);
   ```

   <sup>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YPmkCk/1)</sup>
2. You'll notice even *with* that change to grab the leading curly brace token, the string you've extracted *still* isn't valid JSON. While not the case with plain-old JavaScript objects, all key names must be encapsulated in quotes; the text you'll be extracting does not do this up front. As such, you'll need to swap out the built-in JSON parser (which is strictly spec-compliant and will *not* parse this data as JSON as-is) for something like [`hjson`](https://pypi.org/project/hjson/), which doesn't implement a spec with this restriction.

   [<sup>Relevant SO thread</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812821/bad-json-keys-are-not-quoted)
3. `re.match()` doesn't behave as you seem to think it does. A dive into [the documentation for this method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) is illuminating in this specific circumstance (emphasis mine):

   > Note that even in `MULTILINE` mode, **`re.match()` will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line**.

   This is important as the string data in `script9` does *not* begin with any data that would be considered "matching" per your pattern. Instead, swap the invocation of `re.match()` for [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) instead.

Making a few more adjustments for the changes described above, your code would look something more like the following:

```
import re
import hjson

script9 = '''    sometext;
var thumbdata = {
  thumbs: [{avatar: "/i/nophoto.jpg", username: "IslandGirlSearching",la:"0 second ",chatid: "0",userid: "2088789", age:"21",city:"Cebu"},{avatar: "/p/2021-08/Cristina266/ava-1629535964.jpg", username: "Cristina266",la:"0 second ",chatid: "0",userid: "2095868", age:"26",city:"Pasig City"}  ] }; 
  var source = sometext;
'''

pattern = re.compile(r"var thumbdata = ({\n.*?);")

m = pattern.search(script9)
thumbs = list(hjson.loads(m.groups()[0]).items())
print(thumbs)
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://replit.com/@esqew/VillainousCandidCylinders#main.py)

outputs:

```
[('thumbs', [OrderedDict([('avatar', '/i/nophoto.jpg'), ('username', 'IslandGirlSearching'), ('la', '0 second '), ('chatid', '0'), ('userid', '2088789'), ('age', '21'), ('city', 'Cebu')]), OrderedDict([('avatar', '/p/2021-08/Cristina266/ava-1629535964.jpg'), ('username', 'Cristina266'), ('la', '0 second '), ('chatid', '0'), ('userid', '2095868'), ('age', '26'), ('city', 'Pasig City')])])]
('thumbs', [OrderedDict([('avatar', '/i/nophoto.jpg'), ('username', 'IslandGirlSearching'), ('la', '0 second '), ('chatid', '0'), ('userid', '2088789'), ('age', '21'), ('city', 'Cebu')]), OrderedDict([('avatar', '/p/2021-08/Cristina266/ava-1629535964.jpg'), ('username', 'Cristina266'), ('la', '0 second '), ('chatid', '0'), ('userid', '2095868'), ('age', '26'), ('city', 'Pasig City')])])
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but i have a question about `thumbs = list(hjson.loads(m.groups()[0]).items())`, is it possible to get a list with lists inside, so i can iterate them and read discts inside?